# Code completion in PhpStorm for JS Cookie

Tags: javascript, webpack, phpstorm, webstorm

There is one question.

In PhpStorm 2017.2 I'm using webpack for frontend assets. But when I've imported js cookie plugin code completion is not working.

How repair it ?

[image]

Comment: http://joxi.ru/a2XZL03h15VjZr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a weird way **js-cookie** module is defined. `npm i @types/js-cookie` should do the thing:

[image]